# carrot2 3.8.1 not reading lucene 4.6.0 index

Tags: lucene, carrot2

When trying to utilize clustering on a lucene index, I get the following error:

> Processing error: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: ChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="M:\files\projects\LombardiNetworks\lucene\index\segments_1"))): 1 (needs to be >between 0 and 0)
>
> org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: ChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="M:\files\projects\LombardiNetworks\lucene\index\segments_1"))): 1 (needs to be >between 0 and 0)

This also appears with the 3.9. snapshot. What am I doing wrong? Did I miss some configuration?

Comment: It looks like we need to [upgrade Lucene in Carrot2](http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1038). Set yourself as a watcher on the JIRA issue to get updates.